# Two-column gather

Tags: amsmath, arrays

I like to typeset something like this

```
\begin{two-column gather}
   A < B + 1,      &   E = 3F   \\
   2 + (-C) > D,   &   G/4 = H
\end{two-column gather}
```

such that each column is horizontally centered.

I would say that `align` is a bad idea because
I do not want to align the `mathrel`s.
I also tried `\begin{array}{cc}`
but the vertical spacing looks weird.
Plus it does not number equations.

Question: what is the proper way to typeset this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{gathered}
   A < B + 1,  \\
   2 + (-C) > D,
\end{gathered}
&&
\begin{gathered}
  E = 3F   \\
G/4 = H
\end{gathered}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Two `&` in between, right? I knew it is a matter of creativity.

Comment: Oh! yes \ I was thinking in terms of `tabularx`. Also, note that with `alignat{2}`, you can control the spacing between the two groups.

Comment: I guess I will do that simply with `\mkern`. I start getting tired of the fancy syntax to do really simple works (things like `\setlength` is just useless). Thanks anyway.

Comment: The second `&` is here to specify there's a newcolumn that begins; whence some spacing added by the environment. As there's nothing to align really, I didn't write the third `&` (don't forget *n* alignment columns require `2*n*–1 & `.